# how to display sub folder name using php

Tags: php

I want to display all the sub folders in side Uploads folder.this is my code

```
<?php
    $somePath='uploads/';


$files = glob($somePath . "*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);


foreach($files as $file)
{

 if(is_dir($file))
 {
  echo '<a href="">'.'<img src="assets/img/folder.png" >'.'</br>'. $file.''.'</a>'.'</br>';
 }
}       

?>
```

but it's display main folder name and subfolder name

eg: 
   uploads/abc

uploads/sub_folder

i want to display only sub folder name.

Comment: A quick fix would be `$names=explode('/',$file);` `$names[1];`

Comment: @madforstrength It's display error now. "Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www.."

Comment: on what line? On `$names=explode('/',$file);` or on `$names[1];`